# Microsoft Store Installation not possible | Error code: 0x80070057

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-store

So, I was trying to install Forza Horizon which I just bought, but I'm getting this weird error when I try to install it.
It says "Download is getting started..." and afterwards "Error..."

So, I tried already a lot of things.

I tried using wsreset, also executed it as admin, but it didn't do anything.
I restarted my pc, reinstalled the store using some powershell command but nothing worked.
I also tried to move the default installation folder or put a cache folder called cache in `C:\Users\lockna\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState`
but nothing worked.
I don't know what to try now.

Did anyone had this problem before and can help me fix it?

Comment: Does the drive you are installing to have sufficient free space?

Comment: Also make sure UAC has not been disabled.

Comment: How did you put a cache folder in a folder that by default you don’t have write permissions to?

Comment: @Mokubai yes it does

Comment: @John UAC, what is that?

Comment: @Ramhound uhm, dunno, I just could do

Comment: UAC is User Account Control and Microsoft Store mandated it be ON at one point. I never turn it off any more.

Comment: should be active

Answer (score 0):

Before starting on the list below, take good backups of your data.

Try the following:

1. Check the Event Viewer for error messages regarding the Store and let us know
   if you find anything
2. Check the SMART data of the disk
   (for example using [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy)),
   and post a screenshot if you want our opinion
3. Run `chkdsk` and if errors run `chkdsk /f`
4. Run *Settings > Apps*, scroll down and click below "Microsoft Store" on
   "Advanced options", then on the "Reset" button
5. If there is still no indication of the error, do a
   [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: I tried all of your things, but it just didn't work. I reinstalled windows and now the store works just fine. But now I'm having a restart loop

Comment: Make sure all your drivers are up to date.  Use the manufacturer's driver update app.

Comment: should be up to date